# How can I make my string property nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to make the Middle Name (`CMName`) of person optional. I have been using C#.net code first approach. For integer data type its easy just by using `?` operator to make in nullable. I am looking for a way to make my sting variable nullable. I tried to search but could not find the way to make it nullable.

Below is my code. Please suggest me how to make it nullable.

```
public class ChildrenInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int ChidrenID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    [StringLength(50,ErrorMessage ="First Name cannot exceed more than 50 characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-z]*$",ErrorMessage ="Name cannot have special character,numbers or space")]
    [Column("FName")]
    public string CFName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Middle Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-z]*$",ErrorMessage ="Middle Name cannot have special character,numbers or space")]
    [StringLength(35,ErrorMessage ="Middle Name cannot have more than 35 characters")]
    [Column("MName")]
    public string CMName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Comment: Time to review answers in erms of C# 8.0 and adjust correct one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types

Comment: I don't understand the question. You left out a `[Required]` attribute which is basically all there is to it. The question should rather be: how can I make a string property *not* nullable when it's supposed to be required? I.e. `CFName` is the real challenge here. Using *nullable reference types* helps, but still doesn't enforce it.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

String is a reference type and always nullable, you don't need to do anything special. Specifying that a type is nullable is necessary only for value types.

Comment: this is not entirely true for c# 8+.with c# 8+ string will be still nullable bu with 
#nullable enable
you may use nullable operator as well for strings.

Comment: In C# 8.0 reference types may be marked as nullable. One may type `string?` to tell the world this string may be null. Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdC0aoa7ung

Comment: @cahit, do you mean the null-coalescing operator? You can use that without specifying a nullable string.

Comment: wrong answer for the question asked.  adding an ? on there would also be required to cover serialization / deserialization scenarios

Answer (score 37):

[C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) is published now, so you can make reference types nullable too. For this you have to add

```
#nullable enable
```

Feature over your namespace. It is detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

For example something like this will work:

```
#nullable enable
namespace TestCSharpEight
{
  public class Developer
  {
    public string? FullName { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }

    public Developer(string fullName)
    {
        FullName = fullName;
        UserName = null;
    }
}}
```

If you want to globally set nullable property for whole project; you can do it  in **.csproj** file by adding

> `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

property to PropertyGroup. It will enable nullablity for all classes in the project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> 
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> 
   </PropertyGroup>

 <!-- Other Settings --> 
 </Project>
```

Also you can have a look [this nice article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/04/21/first-steps-with-nullable-reference-types/) from John Skeet that explains details.

Comment: that piece of code would work prior to c# 8.0, wouldn't it?
It is just assigning some null value to a property.

Comment: You can not make reference types nullable prior versions of c# 8.0.

Comment: I think @ShahryarSaljoughi's point is that your code makes no use of the new `string?` type.

Answer (score 15):

System.String is a reference type so you don't need to do anything like

```
Nullable<string>
```

It already has a null value (the null reference):

```
string x = null; // No problems here
```

Answer (score 7):

Strings are nullable in C# anyway because they are reference types. You can just use `public string CMName { get; set; }` and you'll be able to set it to null.

Comment: Every type is an object in C# (through inheritance). The reason `string`s are nullable is because they're instances of a reference type.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful clarification. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while when the question has been asked and C# changed not much but became a bit better. Take a look [Nullable reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types)

```
string notNull = "Hello";
string? nullable = default;
notNull = nullable!; // null forgiveness
```

C# as a language a "bit" outdated from modern languages and became misleading.

for instance in `typescript`, `swift` there's a "?" to clearly say it's a nullable type, be careful. It's pretty clear and it's awesome. C# doesn't/didn't have this ability, as a result, a simple contract IPerson very misleading. As per C# FirstName and LastName could be null but is it true? is per business logic FirstName/LastName really could be null? the answer is we don't know because C# doesn't have the ability to say it directly.

```
interface IPerson
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
}
```

Comment: You omit the most important part, i.e. that C# can be made nullable aware now.

Comment: C# allows you to now explicitly specify that the value can be null, but you still can't require the string to not be null with an interface, so the point is kind of moot.

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem with `null` in Entity Framework

To fix your problem, try this:

```
    //[Required] <<< remove this
    ...
    public string CFName { get; set; } = null;// set default value to null
```

### Here is the Confusion

For starters, a string property in C# is a *reference type*. That means by default its a `nullable type` and can be assigned `null` or any other `value`. They do NOT need to be decorated with nullable operators (like string?) to be nullable or accept null values. But by Microsoft's definition now, they are called *"uninitialized non-nullable properties"*. Crazy huh?

Second of all, most forget, but `null` is an *actual value*. So it is better than NOT assigning anything to a variable or property. An uninitialized variable, field, or property cannot be used till a value is assigned. That is especially true in *Entity Framework*.

The confusion is the fact that **Entity Framework** classes when instantiating your entity classes to receive or assign data to the database must auto-assign values to all your properties. In the case of Value Types like `int` its pretty easy as those have three possible states: An `assigned value`, `null` if set as nullable, or a default value which is `0` if not nullable.

When using `strings` in *Entity Framework* it is a whole different ball game...

For starters, *Reference Types* like `string` or `object` (your Types) in *Entity Framework* now trigger a null check error during compilation. Why? They should default to `null`, right?

The reason is they now fall into a state of either `non-null` or `maybe-null` (Microsoft definitions) now. All *reference types* are `nullable` types plus can accept `nulls`. But if not explicitly assigned a value, like a nullable type or empty string, remain vulnerable to unexpected null assignments. So EF and the compiler does not like them! They actually become `maybe-nulls`. This means that Entity Framework does not know what the default should be, null or not null, nor if the table column should accept NULL. By default in EF, using code first, plain string types therefore create non-null columns, which adds **more confusion** (and likely what the poster experienced).

The best way to settle all this is to just be as explicit as possible and avoid *[Required]* which does not help with defining the intent, since you can still assign a default of null which goes against the use of required properties.

A better way I have found is to set the property in your entity classes to either explicitly support non-nulls or nulls using defaults, and add the `nullable` operator (?) to your strings if they will possibly be nullable in the database, as shown below. Realize that reference types remain as *nullable* and *null-accepting* types by default, even if not explicitly decorated with nullable operators. But to the new compilers, they trigger warnings now because they fall into that gray area of `maybe-nulls` until you explicitly define them and give them a default value:

```
// These support a null in the database and defaults 
// to null if no value provided. But are not clear in intent.
public string CFName { get; set; } = null;
public string CFName { get; set; } = default;// same as null

// BETTER : These explicitly support the string 
// as a nullable type and set a null default for nullable columns
public string? CFName { get; set; } = null;
public string? CFName { get; set; } = default;// same as null

// For support of non-null database columns and strings
// add an empty string default!
public string CFName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
//public string CFName { get; set; } = default;// NO! this is null!
```

In the last case, notice string still defaults to `null`! To me, that means several things. All `strings` and `objects` will always support null. No *decoration* can stop them from using or being `null`, though your tell the compiler your expectations. nullable(`?`) and null-forgiving(`!`) operators do not really help as these types still have the same behavior away from these code points.

Using the keyword **"default"** which then turns into **"null"** on a a type without a nullable operator proves that fact!

Explicitly setting a non-null value on on implicit null like a reference type does not change their basic behavior in .NET and should not. And that is part of the confusion. This whole system they added is mostly for the compilers and the new null alert system they added, not your logic and how types can and should be used, which is using null assignments.

We all hate *null exceptions* and they are the *bane of C# programming*, for sure. But to me **in C# it is better to check for nulls as a "best practices" habit than let compiler warnings do it for you**.

So that is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, string is always nullable in C#. I suspect you are asking the question because you are not able to leave the middle name as null or blank?
I suspect the problem is with your validation attributes, most likely the RegEx. I'm not able to fully parse RegEx in my head but I **think** your RegEx insists on the first character being present. I could be wrong - RegEx is hard. In any case, try commenting out your validation attributes and see if it works, then add them back in one at a time.

Comment: yes they are. but in C# 8 you will now get a warning. its only a warning and it looks like you can still assign null to strings without the null operator: ?. Perhaps a sign of things to come

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is just a warning. You can still set strings to null and the code will still compile and run.

To disable these warnings for your whole project you can set the Nullable flag to disabled in your .csproj file as shown below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2022 and things appear to have changed.
If I declare a string in a class and I don't initialise it in the constructor, the compiler shows me this:

```
CS8618: Non-nullable field 'stringvarname' must contain a non-null
value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as
nullable.
```

To get around this, I can either initialise the field, or declare it as "string?".

Answer (score -1):

`string` type is a reference type, therefore it is nullable by default. You can only use `Nullable<T>` with value types.

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

Which means that whatever type is replaced for the generic parameter, it must be a value type.

Comment: I think you meant value type type rather than struct?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do anything, the `Model Binding` will pass `null` to property without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

string is by default Nullable ,you don't need to do anything to make string Nullable

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to make reference types Nullable. Only value types can be used in a Nullable structure. Appending a question mark to a value type name makes it nullable. These two lines are the same:

```
int? a = null;
Nullable<int> a = null;
```

Comment: *It's not possible to make reference types Nullable* all reference types are implicitly nullable. This is misleading at best