# Handling non-nullable reference types and validation

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have an application with non-nullable reference types enabled and am using a mediator pattern.

In the following scenario I'm trying to create a `TodoItem`. I have a validator that ensures that the `Title` property of `CreateTodoItemCommand` is not empty however, the `CreateTodoItemCommandHandler` has no knowledge of this and so I get a compile time error that I'm referencing a potentially nullable property. I can silence this by using the null-forgiving operator `var todoItem = new TodoItem(request.Title!);` but this feels a bit like a hack. How are others working around these issues?

```cs
public class CreateTodoItemCommand : IRequest<int>
{
    // bound via a web request so can come through as null
    public string? Title { get; set; }
}

public class CreateTodoItemCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateTodoItemCommand>
{
    public CreateTodoItemCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Title)
            .MaximumLength(200)
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class CreateTodoItemCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateTodoItemCommand, int>
{
    public async Task<int> Handle(CreateTodoItemCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // [CS8604] Possible null reference argument for parameter 'title' in 'TodoItem(string title)'.
        var todoItem = new Todo(request.Title);

        // omitted
    }
}

public class Todo
{
    public Todo(string title)
    {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the `?` from `string?`? Strings have always been nullable, although I see [there is new stuff in C# 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853482/how-can-i-make-my-string-property-nullable).

Comment: Why do you have the nullable type If the code doesn't require it?

Comment: You show `new TodoItem(request.Title)` and a `Todo` constructor. Did you mean both to be the same? Why does the latter expect a `string` whlie `Title` is `string?`?

Comment: Updated the question. Todo requires a non null title which is guaranteed as the shown validator will validate and throw if that's not the case.  The title coming from CreateTodoItemCommand must be nullable as it's being bound to a web request so no guarantee that someone doesn't post an empty body

Comment: Can you use a different property? Like `public string NonNullTitle { get { return Title ?? string.Empty; } }`

Comment: @kimsagro, still there?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains for good reasons, so there's no perfect solution.

Apart muting the compiler with ! like this

```
    var todoItem = new Todo(request.Title!);
```

It's the shortest approach, but it's not really safe.

You could also pass a default value :

```
    var todoItem = new Todo(request.Title ?? string.Empty);
```

Or throw an exception :

```
    var todoItem = new Todo(request.Title ?? throw new SomeException(nameof(request.Title) + " was null :(");
```

Or check the title before to call your method :

```
    if (request.Title == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Hey !");
    }

    var todoItem = new Todo(request.Title);
```

The compiler will figure that the property can't be null, so it won't raise warning.

You can also expose another version of the same property that is not nullable. It can be meaningful if you have lots of calls to it, but that does not seem interesting for a such simple case.
It's also possible to mute the warning with a #pragma (but that's not either a good way to handle this in your case)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve :)

If your API has wide public access and you really want to inform the end user that he forgot to enter "Title" - then you really need to stay with string? - but then you will be stuck with .HasValue or SuppressWarnings checks in the Handler method.

But the input requirements should be in the API documentation, then you can change "string?" to "required public string" and if the end user's request does not meet the basic data requirements, they will get an Invalid API Request response. Just like that.

And if this is just an application API - the above way is also correct - you should have client-side validation if the user fills in the title and sends requests with this value.